# Loop over named objects in state and pass to child components with React?

Tags: reactjs

My top level component has exercises in its state. The different exercices are stored under the body part that they work:

```
  exercises: {
    chestAndTriceps: ['Push up', 'Bench press', 'Dumbbell bench press', 'Mountain climbers'],
    backAndBicep: ['Pull up', 'Chin up', 'Dumbbell curl', 'Horizontal row'],
    core: ['plank', 'Sit ups', 'Crunches']
  }
```

From my top level component I need to load a child component for each bodypart, and also pass the exercises for that body part to it. If I code this manually it looks like this:

```
<Child
    bodyPart={chestAndTriceps}
    exercises={this.state.exercises.chestAndTriceps} 
/>
<Child
    bodyPart={backAndBicep}
    exercises={this.state.exercises.backAndBicep} 
/>
<Child
    bodyPart={core}
    exercises={this.state.exercises.core} 
/>
```

How can I loop or map over my state so Im not repeating myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(exercises).map((exercise, index) => <Child bodyPart={exercise} exercises={this.state.exercises[exercise]} key={index} />)
```

I hope I've closed off all of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get array of keys of your object in state and then `map()` to create child components from that array.

```js
let Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {props.exercises.map((el, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>{el}</li>
      })}
    </ol>
  )
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      exercises: {
        chestAndTriceps: ['Push up', 'Bench press', 'Dumbbell bench press', 'Mountain climbers'],
        backAndBicep: ['Pull up', 'Chin up', 'Dumbbell curl', 'Horizontal row'],
        core: ['plank', 'Sit ups', 'Crunches']
      }
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return Object.keys(this.state.exercises).map(name => {
      return <Child key={name} exercises={this.state.exercises[name]} />
    })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the body parts and excersises using `Object.keys(this.state.exercises)` and return an array of `<Child />` components:

```
Object.keys(this.state.exercises).map((bodyPart, id) => {
  return (
    <Child
      key={id}
      bodyPart={bodyPart}
      exercises={this.state.exercises[bodyPart]} 
    />
  )
})
```

**Note:** I've used the iterator index as a `key` but this should be replaced with a unique identifier.

Like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exercises: {
        chestAndTriceps: ['Push up', 'Bench press', 'Dumbbell bench press', 'Mountain climbers'],
        backAndBicep: ['Pull up', 'Chin up', 'Dumbbell curl', 'Horizontal row'],
        core: ['plank', 'Sit ups', 'Crunches']
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const result = Object.keys(this.state.exercises).map((bodyPart, id) => {
      return (
        <Child
          key={id}
          bodyPart={bodyPart}
          exercises={this.state.exercises[bodyPart]} 
        />
      )
    })
      
    return (
      <div>
        {result}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
       <strong>{props.bodyPart}</strong>
       <ul>
         {props.exercises.map((exercise, id) => <li key={id}>{exercise}</li>)}
       </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map to loop through your object and for every one item you return the `Child` component with its relevant props

```
map(this.state.exercises, (oneChild, key) => {
return (
  <Child key={key} bodyPart={key}  exercises={oneChild} />
)}
```